# Organize javascript modules under single namespace

Tags: javascript

I have multiple javascript modules

```
 //accordion.js
    var accordion = function(){
       //code
    }
 //slider.js
    var slider = function(){
       //code
    }
```

I need a way to organize them under a single namespace `MyApp` so that I can share common code between them without having naming conflicts with third party code what is a simple to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to have a global object that contains all your functions.

```
 //accordion.js
    if (typeof MyApp === 'undefined') MyApp = {};
    MyApp.accordion = function(){
       //code
    }
 //slider.js
    if (typeof MyApp === 'undefined') MyApp = {};
    MyApp.slider = function(){
       //code
    }
```